# limit json size in post method in java

Tags: java, json, web-services, httpurlconnection

I have very large json array of strings and want to HTTP post request which accepts atmost 5 MB data at one post call or consider 1000 records(approx) for each call.

JSON:

```
Items:[
    {"Name" : "Chair",
     "price" : "30"},
    {"Name" : "Table",
    "price" : "40"},
    {"Name" : "laptop",
    "price" : "300"},
    ... 
]
```

Java Snippet:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    URL url = new URL("http://example.com");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);//5 secs
    connection.setReadTimeout(5000);//5 secs

    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());  
    out.write("json object");
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
```

Right now I am sending all the json array at once,Can someone help me how to limit the json array so that each time I can send 1000 records(approx) at once as batch.

Comment: Well you have to create your JSON with 1000 items and send it. But since I only see a `"json object"` here, it will not help ;)

Comment: Do you need help in parsing the JSON and splitting it into batches?

Comment: @anchreg: yes, can you help me to split into batches

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
int batch_size = 1000;
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(jsonObj, JsonObject.class);
JsonArray array = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("items");
int numberOfBatches = array.size() / batch_size;
for(int i = 0; i <= numberOfBatches; i++) {
  JsonArray currentBatch = new JsonArray();
  for(int j = 0; (j < batch_size || j < array.size()); j++) {
    currentBatch.add(array.get((i * batch_size) + j));
  }
  //Your POST code
  JsonObject objtoSend = new JsonObject();
  objtoSend.add("items", currentBatch);
  out.write(gson.toJson(objtoSend));
  ...
}
```

It uses the [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library to serialize and de-serialize the data.

Comment: swati, did it help?